# How to plot two X axes in R + Plotly + Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have three columns, *Depth*, *Flow In*, and *Flow Out*. I want to plot *Flow In* and *Flow out* against *Depth*. I want *Depth* to be on the Y axis whereas x1 to be *Flow In* and x2 to be *Flow Out*.

Comment: If you are using ggplot you should give a look at [secondary axis](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html). Yes, it will be a secondary Y axis, but you can add `coord_flip` after to get a kind of secondary X axis.
By the way, do not hesitate to put a reproductible example to get more help.

Comment: Thank You for your reply @Thomas, but I want different columns for X axes, I had already looked into the link you have shared before,but that didnt helped me, as it was for a single column displayed on 2 x axis, I want different columns to be plotted in 2 different x axis.

Comment: OK, could you edit your post with a minimal reproductible example ?

Comment: @Thomas I have added, how my graph should look like. You can check it in the Answer section below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to melt the dataframe using melt() from the reshape2 package. This would allow you to display the values side by side. You could use something like the following:

```
df.p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, value, fill = variable))
  df.p + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") 
  })
```

Another thought, having no background on what your data is, you may consider a waterfall chart if you want to show depth as something always below the x-axis. You can use geom_rect for this.